# Number of couples of integers with a given lcm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find the number $P$ of integers $(n,m)$ such that $\operatorname{lcm}(n,m) = k$? Only $k$ is given.

I only find the number of $n$ such that $\operatorname{lcm}(n,k) = k$.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking to find the number P of pairs $(n,m)$ such that $k=lcm(n,m)$ for a given $k$?

Comment: One could do worse than to write the decomposition of `k` as a product of powers of primes and to wonder what the decompositions of the integers `n` and `m` can be.

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano yes I'm asking that.

Comment: @Didier:  I would call that a good hint and answer

Comment: @Ross Thanks. Done.

Comment: Start modestly, how many pairs have lcm $7$?  What about $4$? $8$? $24$?  After a while you will know exactly what's going on. Then the symbols stuff will be easy.

Comment: Elmi: Any luck with the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

One can consider the decomposition $k=\prod\limits_pp^{v_p(k)}$ of $k$ as a product of powers of distinct  primes and wonder what the decompositions $n=\prod\limits_pp^{v_p(n)}$ and $m=\prod\limits_pp^{v_p(m)}$ of $n$ and $m$ can be.

The hypothesis that $k=\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)$ translates in terms of each triplet $(v_p(k),v_p(n),v_p(m))$ as $v_p(k)=\underline{\qquad\qquad}$. Hence, for a given value of $v_p(k)$, there are exactly $\underline{\qquad\qquad}$ couples $(v_p(n),v_p(m))$ available.

Taking into account every prime factor $p$ of $k$, one gets $P=\prod\limits_p\underline{\qquad\qquad}$.